# In my python code, how to catch an HTTP 500 exception 'raise'd by the imported requests module?

Tags: python, exception, python-requests, http-status-codes, convertapi

In short, I am using the paid convertapi.com service to convert PDF files to text for examination.

If convertapi returns an HTTP 500 response to the conversion request (and I know that it does thanks to the most excellent HTTP Toolkit v0.1.17) my python code crashes despite the try: / except: block already in place:

```
import requests
import convertapi
...
def convertPDFToText(
    inputFilename: str,
    outputFilename: str,
    noticeList: list
) -> [bool, str, int, list]:
    '''Returns
    bool    success = True
    str     outputFilePath
    int     conversionCost
    list    noticeList'''

    try:
        result = convertapi.convert('txt', {'File': inputFilename}, from_format='pdf')
    except Exception as ex:
        logger.error('Error! Unable to convert PDF file ' + inputFilename + ' to text.')
        logger.error('Failed with exception [%s]' % ex)
        return(False, ' ', 0, noticeList)

    if "code" in result.keys():
        logger.info(
            'Convertapi.convert returned code ' + str(result["code"]) + ' ' +
            result["message"])
        logger.info('Convertapi.convert returned code ' + str(result["code"]))
        return(False, ' ', 0, noticeList)
```

So I have a particular inputFilename that, if I send a conversion request, convertapi responds with a '500 Internal Service Error' and this response body:

```
{
  "Code": 5003,
  "Message": "File is password protected."
}
```

The object 'result' above should be assigned this dictionary---but it never makes it.

The traceback from the exception I get starts with this:

```
ts.models    INFO     Logging initiated.
ts.models    INFO     STARTING CODE EXECUTION
ts.models    INFO     preferences file read and stored
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/convertapi/client.py", line 46, in handle_response
    r.raise_for_status()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/requests/models.py", line 940, in raise_for_status
    raise HTTPError(http_error_msg, response=self)
requests.exceptions.HTTPError: 500 Server Error: Internal Server Error for url: https://v2.convertapi.com/convert/pdf/to/txt?Secret=<I've deleted my secret key>
```

Honestly, I'm not sure how the 'requests' module gets involved here. I am using it, but I did not realize/understand that the call to convertapi.com was passing through 'requests'. I'm pretty new to this and still learning.

The traceback seems to clearly indicate that 'requests' is raising the exception - and if you look in the .../requests/models.py code referenced, indeed you see this:

```
936        elif 500 <= self.status_code < 600:
937            http_error_msg = u'%s Server Error: %s for url: %s' % (self.status_code, reason, self.url)
938
939        if http_error_msg:
940            raise HTTPError(http_error_msg, response=self)
```

Having researched exceptions, it appears that if an exception is raised with the 'raise' instruction...there is no trapping it with 'except'?
Because that certainly seems to be what is happening. My code is issuing the conversion request within a try: / except: block specifically to catch exceptions so the code (running on a server supporting a website) doesn't break and provide the user with the (in this case) illuminating message:

```
A server error occurred.  Please contact the administrator.
```

Finally, my question is...can I capture the exception intentionally raised by another bit of python code? Because what I have in place does NOT work.

I've even tried *nesting* the entire try: / except: block within ANOTHER try: / except: block, but no change in result.

```
    try:
        try:
            result = convertapi.convert('txt', {'File': inputFilename}, from_format='pdf')
        except Exception as ex:
            logger.error('Error! Unable to convert PDF file ' + inputFilename + ' to text.')
            logger.error('Failed with exception [%s]' % ex)
            return(False, ' ', 0, noticeList)
    except:
        if "code" in result.keys():
            logger.info(
                'Convertapi.convert returned code ' + str(result["code"]) + ' ' +
                result["message"])
            logger.info('Convertapi.convert returned code ' + str(result["code"]))
        logger.error('Error! Unable to convert PDF file ' + inputFilename + ' to text.')
        logger.error('Failed with exception [%s]' % ex)
        return(False, ' ', 0, noticeList)
```

Yes, I'm sure this is dense, but I'm trying everything I can think of.

I don't think this question is specific to convertapi or requests - I think it is about exception handling, specifically how to handle this particular situation.

Answer (score 0):

You should expect `convertapi.exceptions.ApiError` instead of `Exception`:

```py
try:
    result = convertapi.convert(...)
except convertapi.exceptions.ApiError as ex:
    logger.error('Failed with exception [%s]' % ex)
```

Comment: many thanks. I *CAN* catch the exception using 'convertapi.exceptions.ApiError' although I can't get anything but 'unprintable ApiError' messages and a session crash if I attempt to display the value of ex - so I basically am just ignoring it. Again, many thanks.